# Confidence interval for mean of m predictions

Tags: regression, machine-learning, weighted-regression

I have a gradient boosted regression tree model (catboost).

$y = F(X) + \varepsilon$

I need to compute the following - specifically the 2nd equation below, the first is trivial.

$\frac{1}{m}\sum \limits_{i=1}^m \hat y_i$

$var\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum \limits_{i=1}^m \hat y_i\right)$

The issue is the variance of the forecast residuals varies with time. There's a daily and annual cycle (possible weekly as well), i.e.

$\varepsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\Omega\right)$

I'm not sure if the 2nd term is the `prediction interval` or `confidence interval`?

One option is bootstrapping to create N seperate estimators then compute the statistics I need over the N results? But I'm not sure that the variance of N bootstrapped forecasts is the same as the variance of the prediction given the covariance of $\varepsilon$?

Alternative is to estimate $\Omega$. In which case how could I approach this? Clearly I need to be able to fit $\Omega(X_{train})$ and predict $\Omega(X_{test})$?

Comment: Are you sure that $\hat y = F(X) + \varepsilon$ has $\hat y$?

Comment: *I'm not sure if the 2nd term is the prediction interval or confidence interval?* It is none of them. For a confidence interval you need at least two things - error that is tolerable, which basically makes the interval i.e. estimate +- error, and the probability that the estimated parameter falls in that interval. Rather it is just the variance of the mean of the fitted Y values. This can be used to get a confidence interval

Comment: Thanks, not sure what you mean in your first comment though? What I'm trying to say is the predicted y is F(X) + error.

Comment: It seems there is a flaw in your reasoning. You cannot predict errors that you would make.

Comment: Generally $\hat y$ is used to denote fitted mean response, $y$ to denote the actual values (sample) of the response variable and $ y = F(X) + \varepsilon$ is the model.

Comment: I think it's a flaw in the way I've written it - I understand what you mean. It should by \hat y = y + e I think?

Comment: Yes, you are right about it. You could also make it $\hat y = y - \varepsilon$. This notation is generally followed.

Comment: Yeah =()+ and ̂ =() right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99489/discussion-between-david-waterworth-and-naive).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure if the 2nd term is the prediction interval or confidence interval?

It is none of them. For a confidence interval around any estimate, you need at least two things

1) error that is tolerable, which basically makes the interval i.e. estimate $\pm$ error

2) confidence level - the probability that the estimated parameter (population parameter) falls in that interval.

Comment: Thanks, I think what I need to focus on is either being able to create an estimate for cov(e|X) - ie parametrically, or eliminating the heteroskedasticity - which I've had made some progress today, by fitting a parametric model to e^2 and then passing this back to the estimators as sample_weight (I'm using CatBoostRegressor) the residuals appear to have fairly uniform variance and the ACF is closer to AR(1)

Comment: I have not had the opportunity to work on CatBoostRegressor. If you can link the material which you are covering then I think I might be of help further.